# Matrix multiplication with inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two constants a,b and an Identity matrix p x p. Does $ (aI)^{-1}(bI) = (a/b) I? $ If not, can this be written in a simpler form where we get constants separated from the identity matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get $b/a$, as in $(aI)^{-1}(bI)=(b/a)I$.

Intuitively,  $(aI)^{-1}$ just has $1/a$'s on the diagonal,  or equals $1/aI$ would perhaps be a better way of putting it.   Now $(1/a)I(bI)=(b/a)I$, because $bI$ just has $b$'s on the diagonal.   When you multiply diagonal matrices,  you just multiply corresponding diagonal entries.

Try an example or two, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you Chris! That makes sense. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

$(aI)^{-1}(bI)=\frac b a I$ if $a \neq 0$. $(aI)^{-1}(bI)$ does not exist if $a=0$.

Comment: Can you explain the intuition behind it a bit?